# Is there a function to create a regex pattern from a string input?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm lousy at regular expressions but occasionally they're the only thing that's the right solution for a problem.

Is there something in the .NET framework that allows you to input an unencoded string and get a pattern from it? Which you could then modify as required?

e.g. I want to remove a CDATA section that contains a file from some XML but I can't work out what the right pattern is for `<![CDATA[hugepileofrandombinarydataherethatalsoneedstogo]]>` and I don't want to ask for help each time I'm stuck on a regex pattern.

Comment: well, err... http://txt2re.com helps me most of the time when my brain is to lazy to work it out itself

Comment: As I share your problem, I propose a slightly different approach:  verbal expressions. There's a good implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/walkhard/VerbalExpressionsSharp).

Comment: @RubensFarias et al I'm perfectly capable of creating a regex expression given enough time and resources. The problem is that it's one of those areas that is tricky, difficult to get 'just right', and can only be validated by extensive testing and therefore very time consuming. I could simply ask for help each time but what I'd like to do is reduce the time it takes to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but as there is no suitable .Net component the [text to regex page at txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com/) is the best I've seen for those people who occasionally need to build a regex to match a string but don't have the time to relearn regex each time they want to use one.

Answer (score 1):

Such tools exist, google by "regex generator".
But, as suggested in comments, better learn regex. Simple patterns are easy. Something like `<!\[.*?]]>` 
in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are Regex Design tools like expresso...

http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm